# How to Initialize a Web Component From Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

Let's say I have the following web-component:

```
<link rel="import" href="my-dialog.htm">

<my-dialog id='mydialog1' heading="A Dialog">Lorem ipsum</my-dialog>
```

See here for more info: http://cbateman.com/blog/a-no-nonsense-guide-to-web-components-part-1-the-specs/

and here: http://www.revillweb.com/tutorials/web-component-tutorial/

However, apart from attributes sometimes I'd like to initialize it with some object that has a bunch of properties for example:

```
var obj = { heading: 'hello there', data1: 123, name: 'blabla' };
//^^ this can be any type of data.. think some kind of data model here, and maybe I get this model from the server.
```

So I can't send the above object within my html via attributes, cause I might have alot of settings and/or I might get it at a later point from the server, so I need to do it in javascript.

So what I've been doing is I've just been taking the object after it has been created:

```
// initialize is a function I have inside my web component
$('#mydialog1').get(0).initialize(obj);
```

^^ And this works, initialize(..) is a function inside my web component.. But:

**Question #1 I wonder if this is the correct way to initialize a web component, as it seems a bit messy.**

Also, if one instantiates a web-component in code:

```
$('body').append("<my-dialog id='bla'></my-dialog>");
$('#bla').get(0).initialize(obj);
```

**Question #2 Can I assume on the second line, that 'bla' has been created here with all its methods?** (funny enough, this works but I thought maybe it'd be better to wait for some kind of event or something that the component is ready)

Comment: What technology is this? What page might we be referred to to learn a little more about it? And what question do you have specifically that isn't answered by that page?

Comment: this is web components

Comment: As in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components ? OK, then. Are you asking how to reliably bind data to a Web Component without running the risk of doing so before it is instantiated?

Comment: yes. and if I'm passing the data correctly through code or if there is a better way.

Comment: Wouldn't you do stuff like that in the "created" callback? Or maybe the "attached" callback?

Comment: Pointy, I'm talking about the index.html that uses this web component, not within the web component itself.

Comment: ?? OK then I have no idea what you're asking. A web component, to really be worthy of the name, should initialize itself. Requiring each page that uses the component do have to do more than simply include the component code and use the component in the HTML seems kind-of wrong.

Comment: Pointy, yes but you need to initialize sometimes. what if you're using the same web component but each web component needs different initialization settings.

Comment: I'm no expert, but aren't you supposed to do that with attributes in the markup? I guess you're right, though, I can imagine needing to do stuff to the elements. I think that the way the things are supposed to work, the callbacks for the component are all made synchronously when the component is added to the DOM (or removed or whatever), so it seems like a regular native element.

Comment: Do you want a cross-browser or a Chrome-only solution?

Answer (score 1):

Because append has a synchronous(opposite of async) behavior, it will always work.

Do not litter your codebase with needless safety nets(events, polling...).

In short, right after .append is executed the element is present on DOM and you can query it with selectors and do whatever you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Like virtually all JavaScript methods, HTML appending is synchronous, which means that you can expect the correct DOM elements to be constructed when the function returns - if not so, the function would accept callbacks or return a Promise or similar. Thus, you can trust that the thing has been created and initialize it. And initializing it in this way is probably the best thing to do (though there might be a way to do it all in one line.)

If you feel the need to convince yourself that a given import method (anything that consults an external file) is synchronous rather than asynchronous, you can do the following on a *nix system:

1. Create one named pipe and pipe `yes` to it. (`$ yes >pipe1`)
2. Create an appropriate HTML (or JS or whatever) header that would make the output of `yes` (an infinite series of `y`s followed by linefeeds) syntactically correct for your situation.
3. Create another named pipe and pipe the header followed by the first named pipe (using `cat`) to it. (`$ cat header.htm pipe1 >pipe2.htm`)
4. Run your import method using the name of the second named pipe. (`<link rel="import" href="pipe2.htm">` or `var x = require("pipe2.js")`)

Does your UI hang? If so, then it's synchronous. Does it keep on going? Then it's asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the attributes via an object? I'd make settings and then pass them this way:

```
document.getElementById("someID").style.width = widthVar; 
document.getElementById("someID").name = nameVar; 
document.getElementById("someID").style.color = colorVar;
```

Comment: I'm not necessarily talking about style settings.. it could be anything passed within a 'settings' object. any type of data.

Comment: And he's talking about web components, which is a method being developed to bring data-binding to native HTML.

Comment: @foreyez - you can create any attribute using the aforementioned. I'd create a script and then link through the obj keys using the key and value to set them accordingly on the element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating it in html:

```
$('body').append("<my-dialog id='bla'></my-dialog>");
$('#bla').get(0).initialize(obj);
```

You can also do something like:

```
var myDialog = document.createElement('my-dialog');
myDialog.initialize(obj);
$('body').append(myDialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

Web components are designed to be interacted with via their attributes, this way they can stay truly interoperable.

If you get your data after you have added the component to the DOM you can still interact with the web component via attributes like this:

Let's say you have your dialog component already added to the DOM:

```
<my-dialog id='mydialog1' heading="A Dialog">Lorem ipsum</my-dialog>
```

So you can easily update this DOM elements attributes at a later time with JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('#mydialog1').setAttribute('init-data', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

And then within the web component you can react to attribute changes as follows:

```
//Called when one of this components attributes change
    proto.attributeChangedCallback = function(attrName, oldVal, newVal)     {
        switch (attrName) {
            case "init-data":
                //DO SOMETHING WITH newVal
                var dataObj = JSON.parse(newVal);
                break;
        }
    };
```

This should give you everything you need. I'd seriously recommend writing your web components with ES2015 the code is a lot cleaner, see this tutorial: http://www.revillweb.com/tutorials/web-components-with-es2015-es6/

Hope this helps!